# Get a user input instead of hardcoding an input into array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to get the user input into a Wordpress query array. I can get the input with my jquery code but i want to add it to the `'meta_value' => '123456',` in the php array. How can i change the`'meta_value' => '123456',` from `'123456'` to the `var x` from the jquery script?

If this is not possible can someone suggest another way to get the `'meta_value' => '123456',` from an input field?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#bt").click(function(){
            var x = jQuery("#txt_name").val();
            alert(x);
        });
    });

</script>

<input type="text" id="txt_name"  />
<input type="button" id="bt"  value="click here" />




<?php

 $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'cardnum',
        'meta_value' => '123456',
        'meta_compare' => '='
    );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->cardnum ." ". $user->nickname . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Not available number.';
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to send that data to server using ajax or in a form. Php doesn't run in the browser. There are lots and lots of tutorials on the web about using ajax  as well as ajax with wordpress

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a form or Ajax - you can use the URL query string instead.

When the jquery function fires, reload the page URL, but this time including a query string which contains the variable.

Then you can extract the variable via PHP.

*(This is the fastest and simplest way to enable server-side processing of a variable which originated client-side.)*

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name"  />
<input type="button" id="bt"  value="click here" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bt").click(function(){
        var x = $("#txt_name").val();
        window.location.href += '?x=' + x;
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
echo '<p>The value of <strong>x</strong> is... '.$x.'</p>'; 
?>
```

Comment: this is describing GET ... so answer is conflicting and also not very complete